# Оператор перебора for C++

Tags: c++, for

В книге Липпмана не работает пример с перебором символов в строке:

```
#pragma hdrstop  
#include <tchar.h>  
#include<iostream>  
#include<string>  
#include<stdlib>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
(19){
    string str("some string");
     //вывести символы строки str по одному на строку
(21) for(auto c : str) // для каждого символа в строке str
        cout << c << endl; // вывести текущий символ новой строки
    system("pause");
(25)   return 0;
 }
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> [bcc32 Error] Main.cpp(21): E2141 Declaration syntax error  
>    Full parser context
>     Main.cpp(19): parsing: int main(int,char * *)
> [bcc32 Error] Main.cpp(25): E2188 Expression syntax
>    Full parser context
>     Main.cpp(19): parsing: int main(int,char * *)
> [bcc32 Error] Main.cpp(26): E2188 Expression syntax
>    Full parser context
>     Main.cpp(19): parsing: int main(int,char * *)
> [bcc32 Error] Main.cpp(26): E2377 For statement missing )
>    Full parser context
>     Main.cpp(19): parsing: int main(int,char * *)
> ```
>
> Компилятор "Embarcadero RAD Studio Berlin 10.1 Update 2 24 x86 x64" (2016 год - **не старый**)

Comment: Это явно не минимальный воспроизводящий проблему пример кода.

Comment: Вы покажите, что у вас в строках 20, 23 (подозреваю, что ошибка как раз в том, что написали вы, а не в том, что было в книге). Вообще, лучше покажите всю функцию `main`

Comment: Полагаю, что слова "[BCC32 Error]" относятся к старому компилятору, который не поддерживает C++11

Comment: дык borland умер задолго до С++11...

Comment: В общем, вместо `auto` напишите `char`

Comment: @selya а что делать с for?

Comment: @Croessmah и то верно(

Comment: @Fat-Zer в свежих версиях правонаследника поддержка c++11 имеется при использовании clang-based компилятора

Comment: Глупый вопрос - а сам компилятор (не среда) какой версии? Что в документации написано о поддержке C++11?

Comment: Информация по RAD Studio очень плохо организована и найти что-то сложно, но складывается впечатления, что эта версия уже должна поддерживать Clang. Должно быть не `bcc32`, а `bcc32c`. Нельзя ли это выбрать в настройках build?

Comment: Почему у вас здесь указана одна версия (2016 год), а в комментариях ниже под ответами - другая (2010 год). Так какую версию вы использовали???

Comment: Сначала была 2010. Попробывал 2016 та же ошибка

Comment: Извините я в первый раз на сайте. Не успел обучится

Comment: @СергейВо не надо кардинально менять вопрос, особенно если уже есть ответы. Задайте новый вопрос с указанием новой версии IDE. Это бесплатно.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, у вас **очень** старый компилятор, так что непонятно, что он умеет.

```
string str("some string");
//вывести символы строки str по одному на строку
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) // для каждого символа в строке str
    cout << s[i] << endl;
```

Это должно вас спасти...

Comment: Embarcadero® C++Builder® XE Version 15.0.3953.35171 
Copyright © 2010

Comment: Сведения о решаемой задаче нужно давать не в комментариях, а менять сам вопрос, который вы задали. Потому что первое, что читает желающий вам помочь это собственно ваш вопрос

Comment: @Сергей Во: Почему у вас здесь указана одна версия (2010 год), а в вопросе - другая (2016 год). Так какую версию вы использовали???

Answer (score 1):

Запись вида `for(auto c : str)` стала возможна только начиная с С++11, как вы сами говорите, у вас компилятор 2010 года, соответственно и поддержки С++11 там нет, попробуйте с другим компилятором, всё должно работать